# Singularities of $f(z)=z/\cos(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, infinity, singularity-theory

Regarding complex functions (in complex variables), I was wondering why the function $g(z)= \cos(z)$ has a singularity at $z = \infty$ but $f(z)= \dfrac{z}{\cos(z)}$ does not.

I am a bit confused about the concept of singularities at $\infty$.

Thank you.

Comment: Both of those functions have essential singularities at $z=\infty$.  A function $f(z)$ has a singularity at $z=\infty$ if $f(1/w)$ has a singularity at $w=0$.

Comment: ah it does? One of the examples I was looking at was $g(z) = \frac{(z^2-1)(z-3)^3}{sin(z)}$ and it said that it only had singularities at the points $z$ where $sin(z)$ was zero. I thought the function above would also not have a singularity at infinity, but I am confused on why for g, this is the case then.

Comment: In most situations, complex analysis deals with $\mathbb{C}$, *not* the Riemann sphere, so most of the time you don't care about what happens at infinity.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: This seems to be a common confusion, but, no, $f(z)$ does *not* have an essential singularity at $\infty$. By definition, an essential singularity must be *isolated* and this function has poles at the points $z_n=n\pi+\pi/2$, with $z_n\to\infty$.

Comment: @TedShifrin you're right, I forgot about that.  Perhaps there should be another word for non-isolated singularities?  *Terrible* singularities?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Indeed :) They certainly wreak havoc as they want!

Answer (score 1):

So, to sum up after all these comments:

$g(z)$ indeed has an essential singularity at $z=\infty$ because the function $h(z)=g\big(\frac1z\big)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$:
$$h(z) = \cos\left(\frac1z\right) = 1- \frac1{2!}\left(\frac1z\right)^2 + \frac1{4!}\left(\frac1z\right)^4+ \dots $$
has infinitely many terms in its Laurent expansion at $0$.

On the other hand, $f(z)$, all appearances to the contrary, does *not* have an essential singularity at $\infty$: $f(z)$ has poles at $z=z_n=n\pi + \pi/2$ and $z_n\to\infty$, and so $\infty$ is *not* an isolated singular point.

Answer (score -1):

For $\,\frac1z\,$ "close enough to zero" ( say, $\;\frac1{|z|}<\sqrt[3]6\;$ ) , we have

$$f\left(\frac1z\right)=\frac1{z\cos\frac1z}=\frac1z\frac1{\left(1-\frac1{2z^2}+\frac1{24z^4}-\ldots\right)}=$$

$$=\frac1z\left(1+\frac1{2z^2}+\frac1{4z^4}+\ldots\right)=\frac1z+\frac1{2z^3}+\ldots$$

which shows $\,f(z)\;$ has a singularity at $\,z=\infty\;$

Comment: I think we have the same problem here as in the other question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404631/finding-the-singularity-type-at-z-0-of-frac1-cos-frac1z/404668?noredirect=1#comment865900_404668). What the OP stated is correct: $\infty$ is *not* an isolated singularity of $\dfrac1{\cos z}$ because there is a sequence of singular points converging to it. I'm not sure what's going on with your Laurent series here.

Comment: In the series for $\cos(1/z)$ you forgot to replace $z$ by $1/z$.  Also $\cos$ is even so its series should only have even powers of $z$.  You will end up with infinitely-many negative powers of $z$.

Comment: Thanks @AntonioVargas, corrected