# Finding the singularity type at $z=0$ of $\frac{1}{\cos(\frac{1}{z})}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I have the following homework problem:

> What kind of singular point does the function
>   $\frac{1}{\cos(\frac{1}{z})}$ have at $z=0$ ?

**What I tried:**

We note (visually) that $z_{0}$ is the same type of singularity for
both $f,f^{2}$ hence the type of singularity of $f(z)=\frac{1}{\cos(\frac{1}{z})}$
have at $z=0$ is the same type of singularity $f^{2}(z)=\frac{1}{\cos^{2}(\frac{1}{z})}$.
We recall 
$$
\frac{1}{\cos^{2}(z)}=1+\tan^{2}(z)
$$

We also note that for any constant $z_{0}\in\mathbb{C}$ the singularity
of $f,f+z_{0}$ are the same, this can be proved by noting the Laurent
expansions of both functions are the same, up to an additive constant.

It remains to determine the singularity type at the origin of 
$$
\tan(\frac{1}{z})
$$

This is where I'm stuck, we didn't study what the Taylor series of
$\tan(z)$.

I also know that type of singularity $$\cos(\frac{1}{z})$$ have, but
I don't know how to connect this with the singularity type of $$\frac{1}{\cos(\frac{1}{z})}$$

Can someone please hint me in the right direction ?

Comment: can you mark the right answer as correct one?

Comment: @JessePFrancis - thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The singularity is *not* an isolated singularity, as $\cos(1/z)$ has a sequence of zeroes approaching $0$ (namely $z_n=1/(n\pi+\pi/2)$). In particular, $0$ cannot be an essential singularity of the function.

Comment: I don't think that's right,  @Ted: first, the expansion for cosine is valid for *any* $\,z\,$ , second we're taking values of $\,z\,$ s.t. $\,|z|\;$ is very large, which means $\,|\frac1z|=\frac1{|z|}\,$ is very small, and thus the *second* expansion is valid.

Comment: No, @DonAntonio, the OP asked for the singularity at $z=0$, *not* at $z=\infty$. We're just so used to doing this analysis at $\infty$. So a Laurent expansion at $0$ won't have any annulus on which to be defined, because of the sequence $z_n\to 0$ of singular points.

Comment: Hello! I just missed that: true, the OP wants that for $\;z=0\;$ and I, out of habit, assumed at "the other end". Thanks, I shall erase my answer now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. J.J. had this right; $z=0$ is an essential singularity of $\dfrac1{\cos(1/z)}$.

Comment: @robjohn The classification of singularities into removable ones, poles and essential singularities are (in almost all books) reserved for **isolated** singularities.

Comment: @mrf: hmm. I need to read again. I thought that essential singularities included these functions with no Laurent expansion. I agree that an accumulation point of singularities is neither removable nor a pole :-)

Comment: @robjohn What would you call the singularity of $\log z$ at $-1$? (Principal branch)

Comment: @mrf: I am [not alone](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135458/limit-point-of-poles-is-essential-singularity-am-i-speaking-nonsense#comment311980_135458).

Comment: @mrf: it is not a singularity on the proper Riemann Surface. I am sorry for the confusion, I was using "*these* functions with no Laurent expansion" as a description of $\cos(1/z)$ and it's kind, not as a definition of essential singularity.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that neither of the limits $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{\cos(1/z)}$ and $\lim_{z \to 0} \cos(1/z)$ exist. Therefore the singularity is of essential type.

Edit: The conclusion is wrong since $0$ is an accumulation point of poles. (See Ted Shifrin's answer below.)

Comment: Are you sure ? 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+z-%3E0+of+cos%281%2Fz%29

Comment: @Belgi: What should that link show? WA, too, claims that the limit does not exist.

Comment: I missunderstood you, I thought you wrote the limits does exist, sorry

Comment: Why do you say that your conclusion is wrong? Your reasoning is completely correct. An accumulation of poles indicates an essential singularity.

Comment: Hold on my last comment. There may be a [definition conflict](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135458/limit-point-of-poles-is-essential-singularity-am-i-speaking-nonsense#comment311980_135458).

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks. I was somewhat suspecting that there might be a conflict. However most of the definitions I found when I checked after seeing Ted's post required it to be isolated.